# Should I (statically) type-check Third-party codes (e.g. using Flow)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, types, tdd, typechecking

I had this question particularly while I was writing my first unit test. It doesn't seem right to statically type check these third-party codes, for instance the return values type of Enzyme/React test utils functions and test framework's callback function type.

I just thought that third-party APIs are like (this)[https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md#shallowwrapper-api] are too long and very likely to be tested.

EDIT: clarified that when I said type-check, I mean by static type-checking like Flow, and not thru unit-testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides here:

- it isn't your responsibility to verify the integrity of 3rd party libraries. You should not get into the business of testing other people's deliveries.
- on the other hand: well written tests are a nice way to explore such a 3rd party component.

And more importantly: a well written suite of tests represents a specification of your expectations to that component. A specification that can be exercised automatically!

Meaning: you can keep such tests around and use them to later verify that newer versions of that component still do what you expect them to do.

In other words: you should balance those two points; for example by restricting your tests to important functionality used by your own code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you should add unit tests in your code-base that specifically tests a third party package, no, I would not do that. They could update their package and your tests would fail - you have no control over that (unless you decide to never update).

You're better off adding unit tests to their code-base through a pull request if you want to make sure it has tests. Otherwise, you should only be testing your code.

If you want to write end to end tests that incorporate other packages, that's fine. But I wouldn't unit test their specific features for them. That belongs in their source.

Comment: Thanks @mariocatch! I'm sorry, I wasn't clear, I've edited my question to clarify that I meant type checking thru static type checker like Flow, rather than thru Unit Testing. (Which I think, when done together, would be unnecessarily redundant, am I right?)

Comment: But I think even it is static type checking, your answer still applies, am I right?

Comment: Notifying you as well on this, @GhostCat. Thanks!